# Can I add a binary to an ASP app at runtime and use it in code

Tags: asp.net, dll, kentico, bin

I am running a kentico app and am extending some user functionality through some custom written code. As a result of that I have written a small object/database library to pull some data from an external database to display through a webpart (ascx file). This is compiled into a DLL I would love to upload to my app.

**My question therefor is:**
Can I manually upload the DLL to the ASP.NET apps bin folder at runtime? Continuously, can I then reference and use this DLL in my code file (ascx)?
*(Attempted sequence below)*

```
 library.dll > /bin
 upload .ascx file
 >>use
```

I've rigorously attempted to read the documentation on the runtime behavior within the IIS, but without much luck. But am curious of which the application will simply reload or break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. The application will be restarted, new dll loaded and then you can use it in the ascx control.